# fix the position of a div inside body

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="inside">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="special-div">
    </div>
<body>
```

I need to have my `special-div` outside container for some js considerations

```
#inside{
     margin:auto;
     width:760px;
}
#special-div{
     position:relative;
     top:200px;
     left:300px
}
```

With the above CSS,the position of the `special-div` changes with change in browser size change?
So,how do i fix the position of the `special-div` irrespective of the browser size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you can use `position: absolute;` instead of `position: relative;` and also you have to define the width and/or height for that.

```
#inside{
     margin:auto;
     width:760px;
}
#special-div{
     position:absolute;
     top:200px;
     left:300px;
     width: 100%;
}
```

If you define the parent div as `position: relative;` then your absolutely defined div will work as below picture

[image]

[picture source](http://project67555.appspot.com/css.html)

Comment: ..and then apply some fixed `width`/`height` to the special div.

Comment: special-div can't have a fixed width as is content is dynamic.

Comment: position:relative also gives same result.

Comment: That's because your parent div hasn't been defined as position: relative